# Copy all images from remote url in PHP

Tags: php, file-io, glob

I need to copy all images from remote url. GLOB is not working.
For eg: URL = http://www.example.com/media/k2/galleries/124
Here 124 is directory name. I need to copy all images from that directory using php code.
How to do that?

Comment: Hi, for fetching any kind of files you need to get ftp connection for accessing to that folder and connect using php's built in ftp connector and then fetch all the images using file operations in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless you've got some fancy filesystem setup, that url is of course http protocol. GLOB is for (local) filesystem operations. Use curl or whatever builtin is used in php for http. btw you will need to know all the urls to download. Just because 124 happens to be a directory on a webserver doesn't matter...there's no DIR command to list all the files (urls actually) on the webserver.

Answer (score 1):

If you have PHP5 and the HTTP stream wrapper enabled on your server, it's incredibly simple to copy it to a local file:

```
 copy('http://somedomain.com/file.jpeg', '/tmp/file.jpeg');
```

This will take care of any pipelining etc. that's needed. If you need to provide some HTTP parameters there is a third 'stream context' parameter you can provide.

Try below code to open a directory and get all its file name

```
  $url='foldername';
  $dir = opendir($url);

  //List files in images directory
  while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
    {

    echo "filename: " . $file . "<br />";
    }
  closedir($dir);
```

...it outputs:

```
filename: a.gif 
filename: file.html
filename: g.gif
filename: gg.html
```

Comment: I dont know the image name. I need to copy all images from that directory. (for eg:: "*.jpg"). How to do that??

Comment: I have added a code above try that.